# Convert a path in properties file for XML and Java usage

Tags: java, spring, properties, path

I have a Spring webapp (it is actually a Spring Integration webapp, but I guess this is a general question) configured using an XML file.

This is the [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) declaration:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class WebappConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Here's a file content excerpt, they're a bunch of file system paths:

```
baseFolder=C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\data
baseFolderXML=C:/Users/myuser/Documents/data
```

They're declared twice because I need the same value in both Java files and the Spring context XML file and I haven't found a way to automatically convert one form in the other.

Sample usage in the context XML file:

```xml
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter order="1"
            channel="filesOut" delete-source-files="false"
            directory="file:${baseFolderXML}/out"
        />
```

Sample in a Java class:

```java
public class RequestToMessageFile {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static String workingFolder;

    // ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        workingFolder = env.getProperty("baseFolder") + File.separator + "in-http";
    }

    // ...
```

Is there a way to only have each path defined once and have it converted when used in the XML file and in the Java sources?

Comment: Could you not just have one path in the xml style, and convert from `/` to \ using String.replaceAll() when utilizing it in java?

Comment: @Chris Good idea, although I'd rather prefer not to have to remember to convert the property each time I read it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is providing and `@autowiring` a class which contains methods for retrieving path properties and converting them to the correct slash type. Then instead of/as well as autowiring your `Environment` object, autowire the path converter class? I will admit it's a pretty ugly work-around for a problem that probably does have a better solution somewhere.